# Bigquery SQL semi monthly date range

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I have a report that has a query that needs to automated so that the data range returned is semi monthly (1 - 15) (16 - end of month)

So, if the report is run on the 1st of the month, the date range is for the prior months 16th - end of prior month.

If the report is run on the 15th, the range is for the current month 1st - 15th.

I am planning to use a between. but I need to be able to dynamically generate the dates for the date_from and date_to range.

Is somthing like this possible (perhaps using current date and some calculation)?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Eric

Answer (score 1):

To generate a range of dates, you can use the [`GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_date_array). For example,

```
SELECT d
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
              CURRENT_DATE(),
              DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY))) AS d;
```

Note that this function is available only in [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/).

To generate a range from the first of the current month to the 15th, you can use the `DATE_TRUNC` function:

```
SELECT d
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
              DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH),
              DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 15 DAY))) AS d;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to easily accomplish this with a function from your database, such as IF(), DATE_SUB() and DATE_FORMAT().  Here's an example of using that which could work in your example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
mytable 
WHERE 
mydate >= IF( DAY(NOW()) >= 15, 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01'), 
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), '%Y-%m-16')
&& mydate <= IF( DAY(NOW()) >= 15,
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-15'),
LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) )
```

*This example is MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @FIRST_DAY_OF_CURRENT_MONTH DATE

DECLARE @FIRST_DAY_OF_PRIOR_MONTH DATE

DECLARE @LAST_DAY_OF_PRIOR_MONTH DATE

SET @FIRST_DAY_OF_CURRENT_MONTH =DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,GETDATE()),0)

SET @FIRST_DAY_OF_PRIOR_MONTH =DATEADD(MM,-1,@FIRST_DAY_OF_CURRENT_MONTH)

SET @LAST_DAY_OF_PRIOR_MONTH =DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,GETDATE()),-1)

IF (DATEPART(DD,GETDATE()) =15)

BEGIN

SELECT * FROM TABLE 

WHERE DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN @FIRST_DAY_OF_CURRENT_MONTH AND 

DATEADD(DD,14,@FIRST_DAY_OF_CURRENT_MONTH)

END

IF(DATEPART(DD,GETDATE()) = 1)

SELECT * FROM TABLE 

WHERE DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN DATEADD(DD,15,@FIRST_DAY_OF_PRIOR_MONTH) AND @LAST_DAY_OF_PRIOR_MONTH

END
```